Nuxt/Vue error `slice` is not a function on computed property
I've been pulling my hair on the following issue for quite a while and can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.
I'm building a Nuxt/Vue app and I want to display a list of users fetched from backend/database.
I can get the users list and display it but now I want to implement pagination and filtering.
Hence I have the following component (simplified):
<script setup lang="ts">
interface UserDTO {
  id: Number,
  name: String,
  email: String,
  roles: String,
  created_at: String,
  updated_at: String
}

// const data = shallowRef<UserDTO[]>([
//   {
//     "id": 1,
//     "email": "admin@example.com",
//     "name": "Admin",
//     "roles": "admin",
//     "created_at": "2024-11-01T04:44:41.000Z",
//     "updated_at": "2024-11-01T04:44:41.251Z"
//   }
// ])
const { data } = await useFetch<UserDTO[]>('/api/users')

const search = ref('')
const page = ref(1)
const itemsPerPage = ref(10)

const filteredList = computed(() => {
  const users = data.value
  if (!users) { return [] }
  const query = search.value.toLowerCase()
  if (query.trim() === "") {
    return data
  }
  return users.filter((user) => {
    return (
      user.name.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
      user.email.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
      user.roles.toLowerCase().includes(query)
    )
  })
})
const displayList = computed(() => {
  return filteredList.value.slice(startIndex.value, endIndex.value)
})
const displayStartIndex = computed(() => {
  if (filteredList.value.length === 0) {
    return 0
  }
  return startIndex.value + 1
})
const startIndex = computed(() => {
  return (page.value - 1) * itemsPerPage.value
})
const endIndex = computed(() => {
  return Math.min(
    filteredList.value.length,
    startIndex.value + itemsPerPage.value
  )
})
const pageTotal = computed(() => {
  return Math.max(
    1,
    Math.ceil(filteredList.value.length / itemsPerPage.value)
  )
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Search…"
      v-model="search"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <select class="form-select" v-model="itemsPerPage">
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
      <option>50</option>
      <option>100</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;entries
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(user, index) in displayList" :key="index">
          <td>
            {{ user.name }}
          </td>
          <td class="text-secondary">
            {{ user.email }}
          </td>
          <td class="text-secondary">
            {{ user.roles }}
          </td>
          <td class="text-secondary">
            {{ user.created_at }}
          </td>
          <td class="text-secondary">
            {{ user.updated_at }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-if="filteredList.length === 0">
          <td colspan="5">
            No users to show
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
      Showing {{ displayStartIndex }} to {{ endIndex }} of
      {{ filteredList.length }} entries
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

But I get errors on filteredList.value like slice or length is not a function

And when I comment the failing lines and inspect I can see the computed property is an array

What am I missing?

And I get the same kind of issues if I use the shallowRef.
Example: Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'UserDTO[] | ShallowRef<UserDTO[], UserDTO[]>'.

if (query.trim() === "") {return data} should this be return users?

You're missing return type on a computed. It's unneeded when you rely on inferred types  but this allows you to immediately spot a mistake like return data

Replacing return data by return users fixed it. Thank you

As often, issue was between keyboard and chair.
Replacing return data by return users fixed it.
Thank you for pointing it out.
